# Using mediaelement.js Flash player standalone

Tags: flash, html, media-player, mediaelement.js

i'm using the brilliant MediaElement.js library to play video. However, i want to try building another interface to the Flash player, but i'm wondering how this works. Most Flash players i know expose their interface using some kind of global Javascript function, but i can't find how this works with the MediaElement.js player. I did find some code in me-shim.js, but i can't quite get how to make this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. You can simply edit the CSS and image files.
2. You can add your own items, like so: http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=loop
3. Or you can use the flash shim and events by themselves, then create your own controls using css/html and the javascript events provided to you.

Comment: 3) is what i want. Is there any documentation on how to do that?

Comment: If you go to the MEJS homepage and scroll to the bottom, you'll see a list of methods and events that you can use. For example, you could create a triangle graphic, put it on the page using html, and then set onclick to MEJS's play or pause method. There is no further documentation because implementation is generic to web development in general.